# iOS sequencer tempo slider is causing app to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, slider

I have created a drum sequencer using Objective C. I want the slider to control the tempo. At the moment, everything works, and the interval between each step is being controlled by:

```
 while (self.running)
        {
            // sleep until the next step is due
            [NSThread sleepUntilDate:time];

            // update step
            int step = self.step + 1;

            // wrap around if we reached NUMSTEPS
            if (step >= NUMSTEPS)
                step = 0;

            // store
            self.step = step;

            // time duration until next step
            time = [time dateByAddingTimeInterval:0.2];
        }
```

So the time between each step is 0.2 seconds. I have tried to implement a tempo slider like so in the view controller .m (the slider has a range of 0.3 to 1.0 so will output similar value to what is currently in time):

```
- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender
    {

        AppDelegate* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        app.tempo = sender.value;
    }
```

and by changing the line in the while(self.running) thread to:

```
time = [time dateByAddingTimeInterval: (NSTimeInterval) _tempo];
```

However, this causes the time between steps to be far too short (tempo is crazy fast) and when any control in the app is touched, it crashes.

I wonder if I need to set up a function like this, but I'm not sure what would go inside to enable the tempo slider to work:

```
- (void)setTempo:(float)tempo
{

}
```

I have tried to be as clear as I can, if anyone can help me I'd be very grateful, thanks in advance

Comment: Are you applying the delay on a spearate thread, different from the main thread?

Comment: No I don't think so, it's in the main thread

Comment: This is bad, Not just for iOS but in general, those kind of action that expect blocking operation ( in your case that delay ) should run in different async thread. in iOS you can take advantage of GCD ( dispatches ) or NSOperation an NSOperationQueue, and the NSTimer. in your case the NSTimer could be the best solution for you. Il try to write as possible solution as answer below

Comment: I see, that would be great, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void) startDrumTick{
    [self.myDrumTimer invalidate]; // stop any current existing timer

    // perform the call to the method 'drumMethodOperation:'
    // every 0.2 sec. NB: drumMethodOperation will run on main thread.
    // this means that if you expect to do long-blocking operation, 
    // you will need to move that op to an async thread, in order to avoid
    // the UI blocking

    self.myDrumTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.2
                          target:self
                          selector:@selector(drumMethodOperation:)
                          userInfo:nil
                          repeats:YES];        
}

-(void)drumMethodOperation:(id)sender
{
    // update step
    int step = self.step + 1;

    // wrap around if we reached NUMSTEPS
    if (step >= NUMSTEPS)
        step = 0;

    // store
    self.step = step;

    // any other needed operation to run every 0.2 secs
}
```

Below an example for an async thread management using GCD

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    // Long blocking operation ( DO NOT PERFORM ANY UI OPERATION, like changing a text label, setting an image to an UIImageView, etc. )

    [self myLongDbQuery];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
        //Perform you UI Updates here
        self.myLabel.text = @"Query done!!!";
    });
});
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

Luca is right about using GCD. If talk about your initial solution. 
Did you set initial value for _tempo? Looks like your bug can be caused by _tempo = 0 initially. As you understand sliderMoved will be called only after some user action so you need to set initial value.

Comment: _tempo is declared like this so I'm unsure. But the min slider value is 0.3 so I don't see how it is an issue? @synthesize tempo = _tempo;

Comment: Problem is that you set value only in this action 
- (IBAction)sliderMoved:(UISlider *)sender
which called only AFTER user change slider value. Therefore you need to specify initial _tempo value during init.